# OpenCV cannot open webcam

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, webcam

I am installing opencv into Raspberry Pi 3 model B with the following guide:
http://hopkinsdev.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/opencv-310-optimized-for-raspberry-pi.html

```
sudo cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE 
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local 
-DINSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -DINSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF 
-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/pi/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules 
-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DWITH_FFMPEG=ON -DWITH_V4L=OFF -DWITH_LIBV4L=OFF 
-DENABLE_NEON=ON -DEXTRA_C_FLAGS=-mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -ftree
-vectorize -mfloat-abi=hard -DEXTRA_CXX_FLAGS=-mcpu=cortex-a7 -mfpu=neon
-vfpv4 -ftree-vectorize -mfloat-abi=hard -DWITH_JPEG=ON -DBUILD_JPEG=OFF 
-DJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/libjpeg-turbo/include/ -DJPEG_LIBRARY=/opt/
libjpeg-turbo/lib32/libjpeg.a ..
```

However, after install, the opencv cannot open the webcam.

So,

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
return cap.isOpened();
```

will always return false.

In addition,

I have also used

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

to add the raspicam to /dev/video0

I am wondering if I need to add anything to cmake to make it compile?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you enable the camera module in `raspi-config`?

Comment: @Gill Bates Yes I did.

Comment: Does `raspistill` work?

Comment: @Gill Bates Yes it works. I also tried RaspiCam_Cv, and it also works. However, OpenCV does not work.